# Could I implement threads in this program to make it faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency

Program: Square number tester

What it does: Tests you on square numbers up to the number you enter

Here's a logic/flow chart of the application

1. Open/run file
2. Show an JOptionPane asking the highest number you want to enter
3. Once entered, show a JFrame with all the questions up to the one you asked
4. Once done, open a dialogue asking whether you want to retry and show a graph of time taken per question.

Source if anybody wants to see what I have so far: https://github.com/Injustice/SquareNumberTester

Comment: How do you think multi threading can speed your application?

Comment: What's the upper limit of input?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking.
Theoretically, the limit is Integer.MAX_VALUE. Practically, there will be an exception thrown after the value is 46,390 (sqrt of max value). However there is no actual maximum bound (as in there is no exception checking if value is too high or low, I am going to implement that now).

Comment: Update: I have implemented what I mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems not by your description of the procedure.

When considering parallel computing you need to consider what parts of your code can be executed at the same time and if these operations have long computational times. Your procedure seems mostly sequential, i.e., you respond to user inputs and cannot make much use of his thinking time.

Consider 2 cases:

- Suppose the computational time it takes prepare a questions is long. You need to prepare many questions after a user input.

  - Sequential: you would make the user wait until all the questions are ready, and then sit idle while he answers.
  - Parallel: you prepare the questions during the time the user answers. The "user thread" will ask the "questions preparation" thread for the next question while questions are being added in the background. The "questions preparation" thread is like a buffer for questions.
- Suppose the computational time it takes to prepare a questions is always shorter than the time it takes the user to answer. In this case there is no difference because there is no waiting time for the user - you prepare the next (one) question while he thinks, and do this repeatedly without needing a questions buffer.

For more information on Java and parallel execution, see the [tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

For information about speedup relative to "how much parallel or squential the code is", see [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: So could I generate questions in a Thread after the input is processed and add them whilst the user thinks? Would it be worth the tiny gain? And if I don't, is there a performance hit if I still synchronize methods?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: probably not (I assume the process is instantaneous from the user perspective). Third question: Writing sequential code as if it is parallel does not performs worse in theory. I'm not sure if there is some small overhead for the JVM when executing concurrency-related code. Parallel code is usually harder to manage (read, maintain etc.) from the programmer's point of view (subjective). See my edits to the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. If you've checked my code (or if you haven't), what would you recommend as a project to get me to develop my concurrency, exception handling and other skills (such as UIs etc)?

Comment: I would read the tutorials on those subjects and follow the exercises or at least the examples. I don't know what kind of project you mean, aren't you asking about the project you linked? Exception handling is mandatory anyway, and you can create a UI for it, and even concurrent operations that do something small.

Comment: I understand them, I just want something to work on after this.

Comment: I'm sure you'll stumble upon new stuff to do by the time you finish this. You can also look in sourceforge for open Java projects.